# Series markers in pandas dataframe plots

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm plotting a pandas dataframe which contains multiple time series.
I have more series than the number of colors matplotlib chooses from, so there is ambiguity in mapping legend colors to plots.
I haven't seen any matplotlib examples that assigns markers as a batch across all series and I'm wondering if there's a way to pass a list of marker styles that df.plot() can rotate through in the same way it chooses colors.

`df.plot(markers = ??)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A for loop would be sufficient:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,-1))

for c,m in zip(df,'oxds'):
    df[c].plot(marker=m)

plt.legend()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I like this. Rather than specifying the markers manually one could also iterate through ```Line2D.filled_markers```, as in [this link](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html)